# A curve fitting by two Lorentz function

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to fit my curve by two Lorentzian functions but i could not fit it properly, i found a lot of examples about Lorentzian fitting but none of this work with my data. Here is my code what i tried,

My Data [enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fjsvc5ocsrmoc5f/Final.csv?dl=0)

```
Loren[q_, A_, q0_, c0_, c02_, n01_, n02_] := If[q < q0, A/(1 + c0^2*(q - q0)^2)^n01,  A/(1 + c02^2*(q - q0)^2)^n02];
nlmdi131u =  NonlinearModelFit[Final, Loren[q, A1, q1, c1, c1, 0.8, 1] + Loren[q, A2, q2, c2, c2, 1, Abs[n]] + Abs[B0], {{A1, 6}, {q1, 1.8}, {c1, 6}, {c12, 3}, {A2, 7.5}, {q2,3.35}, {c2, 2}, {c22, 2}, {n, .8}, {B0, 10}, {B1, 0}}, q, AccuracyGoal -> 2];
Normal[%];
nlmdi131u["AdjustedRSquared"];
nlmdi131u["ParameterTable"];
```

and the output looks[image] like,

Comment: What do you mean by "I could not fit it properly"?  There's nothing wrong with the algorithm performing the fit.  Sometimes the model doesn't adequately describe the data.  Is there some theoretical reason why there should be a sum of Lorentzian functions the way you've defined them?  Or do you see that there are two bumps in the data and figured that you need two?  Nothing wrong with that.  I'm just trying to determine why you settled on the sum of two Lorentzian functions.

Comment: Hi JimB, Thank you for reply. I mean if you carefully looked data you can see two bump one is close to 1.84 of x axis value and another is 3.3, but i could not fit both peaks.